# Writing JSON output with array of objects using Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to reformat json structure using spark process, into a structure containing array of objects.
My input file contain the lines:

```json
{ "keyvals" : [[1,"a"], [2, "b"]] }, 
{ "keyvals" : [[3,"c"], [4, "d"]] }
```

and I want my process to output

```json
{ "keyvals": [{"id": 1, "value": "a"}, {"id": 2, "value": "c"}] },
{ "keyvals": [{"id": 3, "value": "c"}, {"id": 4, "value": "d"}] }
```

What's the best way to do that?

For looking at the example input you can run within scala spark-shell:

```scala
var jsonStrings = Seq("""{"keyvals": [[1,"a"], [2, "b"]] }""", """{ "keyvals" : [[3,"c"], [4, "d"]] }""") 
var inputRDD = sc.parallelize(jsonStrings)
var df = spark.sqlContext.read.json(inputRDD)
// reformat goes here ?
df.write.json("myfile.json")
```

thanks

Comment: Did you try anything? `to_json` maybe? Please produce a [mcve].

Comment: How would to_json transform [[1,"a"], [2, "b"]] =>  [{"id": 1, "value": "a"}, {"id": 2, "value": "c"}] ?
There's need to be transformation on the data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the schema, you'll see that following structure is actually mapped to `array<array<string>>`

```
df.printSchema
// root
//  |-- keyvals: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Unless the number of elements is fixed, you'll need an `udf`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._   

case class Record(id: Long, value: String)

val parse = udf((xs: Seq[Seq[String]]) => xs.map {
  case Seq(id, value) => Record(id.toLong, value)
})


val result = df.select(parse($"keyvals").alias("keyvals"))
```

and result can be converted `toJSON`

```
result.toJSON.toDF("keyvals").show(false)
// +-------------------------------------------------------+
// |keyvals                                                |
// +-------------------------------------------------------+
// |{"keyvals":[{"id":1,"value":"a"},{"id":2,"value":"b"}]}|
// |{"keyvals":[{"id":3,"value":"c"},{"id":4,"value":"d"}]}|
// +-------------------------------------------------------+
```

or written using JSON writer (`result.write.json`).

It is also possible to use strongly typed `Dataset`:

```
df.as[Seq[Seq[String]]].map { xs => xs.map {
  case Seq(id, value) => Record(id.toLong, value)
}}.toDF("keyvals")
```